# When is Momentum Applied in Tensorflow Gradient Tape?

Tags: python, tensorflow, adam

I've been playing around with automatic gradients in tensorflow and I had a question. If we are updating an optimizer, say ADAM, when is the momentum algorithm applied to the gradient? Is it applied when we call tape.gradient(loss,model.trainable_variables) or when we call  model.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(dtf_network,model.trainable_variables))?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`tape.gradient` computes the gradients straightforwardly without reference to an optimizer. Since momentum is part of the optimizer, the tape does *not* include it. AFAIK momentum is usually implemented by adding extra variables in the optimizer that store the running average. All of this is handled in `optimizer.apply_gradients`.